# Syncing environment across multiple computers (vocabulary)

Tags: windows, sync

I am trying to figure out some ways to, if not solve, make it easier for one user to manage 2 or more computers, and I don't find anything useful. This may be because I am not searching for the right thing. I would like some help to formalize my problem.

**Here's the setup:**

I have multiple (Windows 7) computers (Desktop, Laptop, Smaller laptop) that I use in different circumstances. I would like to have access to the same core of applications and have the same settings on each of them.

Such applications include

- small tools (F.lux, Auto HotKey)
- compiler/interpreter (Python, Java, Perl, Latex)
- bigger applications like Eclipse, LibreOffice

For each of them there is a particular solution that kinda work. I have a folder that is synced across all my computers for small portable programs (compilers/interpreters) and manage the PATH and configuration manually. I use the export/import feature in Eclipse. But all of it seems like a lot of overhead. And I have found nothing that would decrease the work required to add new computers to the list.

It seems to me that this is a *common* problem but I have not been able to find any good reads on the subject. It may be because it's hard, but also quite likely because I am not searching for the right thing. So what am I searching for? What is the correct vocabulary to use when talking about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In domain environment, [Roaming Profiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roaming_user_profile) are used for such tasks:

> A roaming user profile is a concept in the Windows NT family of
>   operating systems that allows users with a computer joined to a
>   Windows Server domain to log on to any computer on the same network
>   and access their documents and have a consistent desktop experience,
>   such as applications remembering toolbar positions and preferences, or
>   the desktop appearance staying the same.

There is a way, albeit hacky, to setup Roaming Profiles without domain. Here is two guides, that you can follow:

1. [Synced profiles in windows 7 without server](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-US/6945931f-36c1-4ee8-9717-e4b9b7d8c972/synced-profiles-in-windows-7-without-server)
2. [How to configure true roaming profiles using Windows XP Professional in a workgroup environment using the classic NTFS file permissions (not simple file sharing.)](http://computertips.toups.info/roaming/RoamingXPPro.htm)